# Should I use CONTAINS or CONTAIN?

Tags: word-usage

An example of a miniature Sudoku puzzle is:

[image]

Notice that it consists of four rows, four columns, and four 2 x 2 boxes.

I was thinking of using the following wording for the instructions:

> Fill each empty square with a number so that every row, every column, and every 2 x 2 box **contains** all the numbers 1, 2, 3 and 4 each exactly once.

I am uncertain whether my instructions should use the word CONTAINS or CONTAIN.  Which is better and why?  Any other help in improving the instructions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"contains".  You are not compounding the singular subjects "every row" (etc) to make a plural subject, you are giving three parallel singular subjects.

Comment: Your answer would have been be correct if the 3 items were linked by an "or" instead of the "and". But, considering the "and", I don't share your opinion because the subject of the verb is row+column+box, giving the plural "contain" for the verb.

Comment: @Graffito — The repeated "every" belies that conclusion. Some compromise is needed in language. "Every contain" is just never going to work in English.

Comment: @Graffito If you feel this is incorrect please do write you own answer.

Comment: @ralph.m & JamesK : My comment was just an opinion, but after searching some supporting text to sustain this feeling, I wrote an answer.

Comment: @JamesK could you provide more information due to the new answer? I really want to know what the right answer is.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [Washington university document](https://staff.washington.edu/marynell/grammar/agreement.html) related to verb-subject agreement in case of compounds subjects :

> Subjects joined by "and" are nearly always plural.
> Example => *Ben and Nicholas like to play soccer*.

> Exception: If the parts of the subject are considered a unit, you may treat the subject as singular.
> Example => Crackers and cheese is my favorite snack.

In the OP sentence, the names composing compound subject are linked by an "and". Thus, the verb should use the the plural, i.e. "**contain**".

It may sound weird to some people to use a plural after every, because "every" in itself is singular, e.g. "*every man has certain basic human rights*".
But, between "*every man and every woman has certain basic human rights*" and "*every man and every woman have certain basic human rights*", I will choose the second option.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I would also use the 'contain', considering that we are talking about the plural.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple matter of plural vs singular. You would say that a singular box *contains* things, while plural boxes *contain* things:

- The **box** contains...
- The **boxes** contain...

Although you are speaking about many boxes, we use the words "each" or "every" to refer to *individual* things in a group. So, although all the boxes *contain* numbers, *each box contains* numbers.